# Help me get this design to look right. Folded paper with a sense of depth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I'm designing a site for a client. And I was wondering if I could get some help using shadows to create a "folded" effect on this div. The div overlaps the bottom edge of the header, and I want to give the impression of a crease in the image, where the bottom half lifts off the page.

I've got Photoshop, here's what I have so far (UPDATED):

[image: first attempt]

I needs to crease right at the bottom of the header, and I need a drop shadow that comes off. Could anyone give me some tips on how I could create such a shadow in Photoshop?

Final version:

[image: revised version]

Thanks!

*Edit: New pic, a better example of what I'm going for, help me perfect it if you can. Thank you!*

Comment: i am not getting what you need :( do you have any example image such as what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Similar question with good answers at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/faking-a-page-fold-with-photoshop

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm going for, but my implication is a bit different. I've done some work in Pixelmator, and I've made a new example to show you what I'm after. My first one kidna sucks, give me a minute.

Comment: I updated for new pic.

Comment: this is very easy with the help  of photoshop holdon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve(according to your updated pic) ages ago i did the same for a project,

what you have to do  is just follow this [better drop shadow in photoshop](http://designreviver.com/articles/better-drop-shadows-in-photoshop/) tutorial,
 and you are done, i am  sure this will help you

Comment: In addition to this, I used some of the techniques presented in @Farray's link. I've posted my final above.

Comment: now its looking really great cheers

Comment: just one advise make it bit light its too much black in shadows at last as you like.

Comment: YEs, I realized that and corrected it.

Comment: When i saw the picture, first thing that came to mind was "shadows". For that i will upvote!