# How do i need to process an picture to make it look like the background of this site?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Im currently developing an little game... Im a pretty bad designer and artist so i need a lots of help.

I just found a really cool main menu, which got a pretty interesting background:

[image]

As you can see in the background theres a part of the world map.
It looks really cool, so i downloaded an world map illustration which looks kinda old. I tried to reduce the opacity, but that just made it looks worse. Is there an other way to "create" such an background ?

---

Here's where I'm stuck: I want to add some realistic wrinkles to the following picture, to make it look a bit more used and older. Because i use this texture in a game, i want the wrinkles to have a specific structure ( For example wrinkles positioned to make them look like a square ).

Whats the best way to do that ? What tools do i need ?

[image]

Comment: You mean "other than a bitmap editor"? Something like a displacement map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faking a page-fold with photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/faking-a-page-fold-with-photoshop)

Comment: Try Multiply instead. Play with opacity and modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add new layer above the map, and fill it with white
2. make another new transparent layer
3. make a rectangular selection, choose a large soft edged brush, and create a single rectangle like this by painting on the left edge, and then the top edge.

[image]

4. copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then deselect <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
5. paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> copies of the rectangle and place them in a grid - it's easier if you have Smart Guides enabled

[image]

6. select and group <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> all the rectangle layers
7. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and click and drag the handles to rescale all the rectangles to fit the canvas.
8. Delete the white layer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is it possible to make those squares a bit smaller ? Just tried it but got an weierd result. Its working so far, but at the "end" of the squares the color isnt fully transparent. Heres a picture of what i mean : https://imgur.com/a/sppm9 The black arrows marks the spot. Thanks ! :-)

Comment: @genaray Sure make the rectangles smaller if you want.  When I made my rectangles, I only painted in black.  Did you add some white or to the other edges?  If you did, I guess you could set all the rectangle layers to Multiply mode, that'll get rid of any white areas.

Comment: I don't think this is a very effective method. It will take a lot more work to make it passable vs starting off from an existing texture.

I'd have also added noise to this if you are going this route.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a displacement map with a bit of airbrushing added to it.

Note for this to be most effective your base image should be colored as well.

1. Pick a source texture, I used [this one](http://creativity103.com/collections/Paper/paper_creases.jpg) from a google search for folded paper.
2. Place the texture over your image, scale and adjust the contrast.
3. Next cycle through the channels using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd> keys to find the one with the most contrast. Mine is the blue channel.
4. When you decide on the best one, duplicate the channel to a new document.

   [image]
5. Apply a small Gaussian Blur and save the new file as displacementMap.psd and close it.
6. Switch back to your original file and return the channel view to full RGB.

[image]

7. Turn off the texture layer, select your background and go to Filter>Distort>Displace, select your displacementMap.psd and hit ok.
8. Turn back on your texture layer and change the blend mode to multiply.

---

This is only one way of achieving this effect.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Play around with more settings and filters
- Use dodge and burn to make more natural highlights and shadows
- Use brushes to hide or show parts of the texture.