# How do I give my picture a more "used" or "old" look?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I want to make my picture look more old and used.

How do I do that? Is there a tool for doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab yourself a paper texture...

[image]

Place it on a layer above, set the layer's blend mode to Multiply...

[image]

You probably want to adjust the levels on the paper texture, adjust the color levels, opacity etc. but there's no rules here... just experiment. You probably want to spend longer than I did searching for the right texture too.

As a side note, if you're going for the same look as [your previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/102774/52050) then you need more texture all round; the UI and everything in the example is very textured.

---

<sup>Image source: http://www.wildtextures.com/free-textures/blank-retro-paper-texture/

(it was the top search result for "free paper texture")</sup>

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! Im new to graphic Design, so im glad for every help I can get :-).